# How can I remove MvcMailer, T4Scaffolding, and other dependancies and restore my program?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I tried to install MvcMailer and as soon as I added the package my project it died.  I started getting all kinds of error messages concerning dependency conflicts with different versions of  T4Scaffolding..versions 1.0.7 and 1.0.8.  So I uninstalled the MvcMailer.

When I run the program I still get the same message:  A different version of T4Scaffolding is already running in this instance of Visual Studio
Please restart Visual Studio to avoid unexpected behavior.
You won't be able to use scaffolding until you restart Visual Studio.

And my models have error message like:

The type or namespace name 'ColumnAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Or

The type or namespace name DatabaseGenerated could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using EntityFramework 4.50501 SP1Re    l.

MvcMailer seems like a great idea but since I installed it I can't run my program anymore.  Is there anyway that I can simply get back to having my program revert back to the settings before I installed MvcMailer?

Answer (score 1):

In the root of your project there'll be a Packages folder.  Deleting T4Scaffolding version 1.0.7 should resolve the conflict.